# Diccionario, acceder a la clave. c#.net

Tags: array, .net, lista

Dispongo de una variable que almacena un diccionario retornado por un método, es decir, en la variable se llama a un método y éste retorna un diccionario.

```
var listofchamps = SAPI.GetChampions(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, data).Champions.Values;
```

Adjunto la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podría iterar todas los enteros devueltos con un foreach tal que así:

```
    foreach (var something in listofchamps)
    {
        if(something.Id == champ_id) { Console.WriteLine(something.Name); break; }
    }
```

Sin embargo pienso que es poco eficiente, porque necesita cargar una por una la key, haciendo comparación entre el id de la lista y el id actual por el usuario.

Me preguntaba como podría obtener directamente el string dandole el valor tal qué así:

```
listofchamps[champ_id];
```

de esta forma acceder al string sin necesidad de llamar al foreach.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes buscar en la lista con el metodo Where tal que así:

```
IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic> enumerableWhere = listofchamps.Where(champ => champ.Id == champ_id)
```

Luego deberías comprobar si enumerableWhere tiene algún elemento, por ejemplo con

```
enumerableWhere.Any()
```

ya que puede que no exista un campeón con la ID que buscas. 
Por último, si la ID es única, enumerableWhere debería contener un único elemento, puedes acceder a el con

```
enumerableWhere.First()
```

Comment: Hola, primero que todo gracias y perdona por la molesta, cuando intento aplicar el enumerable, me tira un error, las posibles correciones son generar la interna enumerable o llamar a IEnumerable. Por otra parte ChampionStatic no lo reconoce como un tipo. (En esto ando un poco perdido, porque hasta ahora la mayoría lo declaro como var, no sé exactamente el tipo al que corresponde). Por último no termino de comprender por qué champ => champ.id == idBuscada (continuo en un nuevo comentario)

Comment: En cuanto al diccionario no sé realmente como estará montado internamente, imagino que algo como "Nombre1" => 1; "Nombre2" => 2; y así... y en cuanto al Id con el que necesito que haga match up en el diccionario es un id único e irrepetible para cada ejecución. (El id es el que está almacenado en la variable champ_id), por eso me perdí un poco al ver champ => champ.Id, lamento la molestia...

Comment: En cuanto al Enumerable tienes razón, es IEnumerable. ChampionStatic es del tipo de la API de Riot, el nombre completo sería RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic. Y por último IdBuscada es un nombre que me he inventado yo porque no se de donde obtienes la ID que quieres buscar, en tu caso sería champ => champ.Id == champ_id. Actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Curiosamente ese fue el tipo que intrudicí el cuál al principio no me lo leía (Imagino que porque intente con "Enumerable" (a traves de una clase interna que generó Visual studio) ). Ahora todo funciona bien en cuánto a sintaxis, el problema es que lo que me devuelve es "RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic" en lugar del string al que pertenece el entero desconozco por qué

Comment: Disculpa pero no entiendo el problema, con esto obtienes el campeón al cual pertenece esa ID. ¿Qué string quieres obtener?

Comment: Con string me refería al nombre del campeón, pero al hacer un Console.WriteLine() éste devuelve en su lugar "RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic" y no el nombre.

Comment: Ahora que has obtenido el campeón puedes acceder a sus propiedades, en concreto para obtener el nombre tienes que acceder al atributo Name, por ejemplo con enumerableWhere.First().Name, aquí tienes todos los atributos de la clase ChampionStatics https://benfradet.github.io/RiotSharp/api/RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.ChampionStatic.html#RiotSharp_StaticDataEndpoint_ChampionStatic_Name

Comment: Pffff... Y yo poniendo Name después del first, y visual studio me decia que no tenía propiedades (me estoy volviendo loco porque con el foreach aparecian nuevas propiedades, y sin él no y dios, jaja) ... De veras que perdona por todo este mareo, muchisimas gracias de verdad... :)

Comment: Me alegro de que lo solucionaras. No estoy familiarizado con la API de Riot pero seguramente habrá alguna forma más fácil de hacerlo. Te aconsejo que mires un poco las propiedades y las clases de las que dispone la API para que te resulte más fácil. Además te recomiendo que no uses var y declares los objetos con el nombre de su clase, esto te ayudará a saber que es cada cosa, además así los IDE como Visual Studio pueden ayudarte diciéndote que atributos y métodos tiene cada objeto. Un saludo! :)